# How to add TIN surface Z values into Z field of line vertices in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, tin, z-value, data-transfer

I want to transfer Z values of TIN surface into Z field of line vertices. This line feature class is covered by this TIN surface. I used interpolation shape tool but this tool is disrupting line during interpolating process (Linear Method). Is there any other way to write Z values of this TIN surface into the z field of line vertices?

Comment: It means something wrong with your line

Comment: I don't think so, especially curve areas of line were slipped or changed after interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but you will no longer be able to use the line, you will have to use the vertices as points. I'll share here with you a more elaborate answer on how to extract heights from a TIN:

1. The easiest way for me to extract heights from a TIN is [TIN Node](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/tin-node.htm), although this is a link for PRO, the process is the same for ArcMap; just add a field name in **Spot Field**, otherwise you will get a ShapeZ and you will to calculate the Z field by yourself.
2. Extract set of lines at a specified interval. Use [Surface contour](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/surface-contour.htm) to extract the lines and you get height data.
3. What you need is quite easy to get. Use [Surface contour](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/surface-contour.htm) for line extraction, if you need the points to be at a certain distance for each other, use [Densify](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/densify.htm) , then use [Feature vertices to points](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-vertices-to-points.htm) to covert your lines vertices to points and after all this use [Extract values to points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm) or [Add surface information](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-surface-information.htm) for populating your points with height data.

This should solve your issue, although I would recommend TIN Node for getting height data. This recommendation depends on what was used to create the TIN; the source of data is important. Share more details to get more help.